# How to "Fold a word" from a string. EX. "STACK" becomes "SKTCA". C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how to can fold a word from a string. For example "code" after the folding would become "ceod". Basically start from the first character and then get the last one, then the second character. I know the first step is to start from a loop, but I have no idea how to get the last character after that. Any help would be great. Heres my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

string fold;
cout << "Enter a word: ";
cin >> fold;
string temp;
string backwards;
string wrap;


for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fold.length(); i++){
     temp = temp + fold[i];
}

backwards= string(temp.rbegin(),temp.rend());

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
    wrap = fold.replace(backwards[i]);

}

cout << wrap;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try writing some code.  We'll be here to help if you have code which contains a bug, or are somehow stuck on syntax for something specific.  But all you've done is described the assignment.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry about that. I just did not know how to start. But now I have the edited question code. What I'm trying to do is I first added the string into a 'temp' string, then I reversed it in 'backwards'. What I'm now stuck is how can I call the backwards, and make it replace every other character not including the first letter.

Comment: Your first loop can be replaced by `temp = fold`.  That's all it does.   As for the rest, keep working at it.  Use a piece of paper to write down the operations that need to be performed.  You can do it.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that I did not even need the first loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Supreme, there are number of ways to do your task and I'm going to post one of them. But as @John had pointed you must try your own to get it done because real programming is all about practicing a lot. Use this solution just as a reference of one possibility and find many others.

```
int main()
{
    string in;
    cout <<"enter: "; cin >> in;

    string fold;

    for (int i=0, j=in.length()-1; i<in.length()/2; i++, j--)
    {
        fold += in[i];
        fold += in[j];
    }
    if( in.length()%2 != 0) // if string lenght is odd, pick the middle 
        fold += in[in.length()/2];

   cout << endl << fold ;

   return 0;
}
```

good luck !

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this form of problem,  a mathematically exact method would be to create a generator function which returns the number in the correct order.

An easier plan would be to modify the string to solve practically the problem.

### Mathematical solution

We want a function which returns the index in the string to add.  We have 2 sequences - increasing and decreasing and they are interleaved.

sequence 1 :

```
0, 1 , 2, 3.
```

sequence 2

```
len-1, len-2, len-3, len-4.
```

Given they are interleaved, we want even values to be from sequence 1 and odd values from sequence 2.

So our solution would be to for a given new index, choose which sequence to use, and then return the next value from that sequence.

```
 int generator( int idx, int len ) 
 {
     ASSERT( idx < len );
     if( idx %2 == 0 ) {  // even - first sequence
         return idx/2;
     } else {
         return (len- (1 + idx/2);
     }
 }
```

This can then be called from a function fold...

```
std::string fold(const char * src)
{ 
    std::string result;
    std::string source(src);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        result += source.at(generator(i, source.length()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Pratical solution

Although less efficient, this can be easier to think about.  We are taking either the first or the last character of a string.  This we will do using string manipulation to get the right result.

```
std::string fold2(const char * src)
{
    std::string source = src;
    enum whereToTake { fromStart, fromEnd };
    std::string result;
    enum whereToTake next = fromStart;
    while (source.length() > 0) {
        if (next  == fromStart) {
            result += source.at(0);
            source = source.substr(1);
            next = fromEnd;
        }
        else {
            result += source.at(source.length() - 1); // last char
            source = source.substr(0, source.length() - 1); // eat last char
            next = fromStart;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the concept of [reverse iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) to write a generic algorithm based on the solution presented in [Usman Riaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139961/4944425) answer.

Compose your string picking chars from both the ends of the original string. When you reach the center, add the char in the middle if the number of chars is odd.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class ForwardIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt fold(ForwardIt source, ForwardIt end, OutputIt output)
{
    auto reverse_source = std::reverse_iterator<ForwardIt>(end);
    auto reverse_source_end = std::reverse_iterator<ForwardIt>(source);
    auto source_end = std::next(source, std::distance(source, end) / 2);
    while ( source != source_end )
    {
        *output++ = *source++;
        *output++ = *reverse_source++;
    }
    if ( source != reverse_source.base() )
    {
        *output++ = *source;
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> tests {
        {"", ""}, {"a", "a"}, {"stack", "sktca"}, {"steack", "sktcea"}
    };

    for ( auto const &test : tests )
    {
        std::string result;
        fold(
            std::begin(test.first), std::end(test.first),
            std::back_inserter(result)
        );
        std::cout << (result == test.second ? "  OK    " : "FAILED: ") 
                  << '\"' << test.first << "\" --> \"" << result << "\"\n";
    }
}
```